# async await (again) inside lambda

Tags: task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

I was reading a few blogs about async & await, particularly that of [Scott's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToParallelBasicsDontBlockYourThreadsMakeAsyncIOWorkForYou.aspx) . I have a code sample below, which presumably downloads a list of URLs. To simplify things and make the timings reasonable and repeatable, I replaced the real download code with a *Task.Delay* awaitable call.

The first code doesn't have an async-await pair inside the lambda expression, while the second one has. Both codes compile, and both timings come out the same (around 1 second).

1.) Which method is the right way to do this?

2.) Will the await async pair inside the lambda cost more?

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // Capture the UI synchronization context for use later
  var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

  // SAMPLE 1 , is this the right way?
  var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();
  var sp = new Stopwatch();
  sp.Start();
  // NO await async pair in lambda
  var results1 = await Task.WhenAll(
                            items.Select(item => DownloadFileAsync(item)));
  sp.Stop();
  var testResult = string.Format("Single await: {0} seconds"
                                   , sp.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
  // SAMPLE 2, or this way?
  var items1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();

  var sp1 = new Stopwatch();
  sp1.Start();
  // WITH await async pair in lambda
  var results = await Task.WhenAll(items1.Select(async item => 
                                      await DownloadFileAsync(item)));
  sp1.Stop();
  var testResult1 = string.Format("Double await: {0} seconds", 
                                      sp1.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
  // show results
  await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
     MessageBox.Show(testResult + System.Environment.NewLine + testResult1);
  }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, 
                                ui).ConfigureAwait(false);    
}
```

and

```cs
private async Task<string> DownloadFileAsync(string uri)
{
    //using (var client = new WebClient())
    //{
    //  string data = await 
        client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
    //  return data;
    //}
    
   await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
   return uri;        
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of them are roughly equivalent. The first one is slightly more efficient.

For the purposes of this question, you can think of

- `await` as "unwrapping" a task, and
- `async` as "wrapping" a method in a task.

The first example uses a lambda expression to define a function with the signature `Task<string> F(string)`. The function defined by the second example has the same signature. The difference is that

- the first example just returns the task from `DownloadFileAsync` directly
- while the second example unwraps the task and then wraps it again.

Comment: Is there another way to "visually" see the difference?  E.g. viewing the IL code?

Comment: @alpinescrambler: Yes; the code generated by the compiler is extremely different.